# Changing Ajax data dynamically using a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below passes four parameters (names) to a PHP file and it works fine. 
Because in my application I have more than 4 names that change with time, I tried to use a loop with array and specify "n" as the number of names that I may have.
I could not find a way that made it work correctly. Can you show me how to change the working code below to include a loop where the number of names "n" is a variable.

```
var name1 = "a";
var name2 = "b";
var name3 = "c";
var name4 = "d";

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test12.php',
    data: { par1: name1, par2: name2, par3: name3, par4: name4 },

});
```

Thnak you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If all the names are globals, I would do:

```
var data = {}, n = 4;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    data['par'+i] = window['name'+i];

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test12.php',
    data: data // can be short-handed as "data" instead of "data: data"
});
```

If they are not globals, I would put the names in an array, and then loop through them this way instead:

```
var data = {}, names = [name1, name2, name3, name4], n = names.length;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    data['par'+i] = names[i-1];

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test12.php',
    data
});
```

Comment: its not really short-hand the other way will post everything to $_POST['data']

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first part (globals) works great. I tested it.
Your second part, when the names are not global may not work for me because I do not know how many names I may have therefore I cannot specify
var names = [name1, name2, name3, name4]

Comment: @Pamblam What makes you think that? jQuery will call [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) on `data`. `data` itself is not what gets sent.

Comment: I am probably missing something because i am quite new to jQuery. Can you show the whole code as you did with the first part and I will test it. I understood completely the first part. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Menachem Sure, I just omitted it because the code was identical for the second part. Updated now.

Comment: I probably was not clear with my question. If I have to write:
var names = [name1, name2, name3, name4]
this means that I have to know from the beginning the number of names that I have. However I do not know it. The first part did not have this requirement.

Comment: because data is an array. write it out: {data:data} = {data: {param:"val", param2: "val2"}} is a 2d "associative array"

Comment: @Pamblam I'm not sure we're on the same page. The shorthand is used for when the name of the variable is the same as the name of the name/value pair. I was just saying that you don't have to write it twice like that when the names match. It won't be 2D, it will expand to have `data` on the left, and the value of `data` on the right. I'll edit to show what I mean

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. Everything is clear now.

Comment: If you question is answered, check the tick mark next to the answer so that people will know it solved the problem.